# Tunneling multicast over SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, multicast, reverse-tunnel

There's a remote server which has a LAN interface configured with IP address `192.168.100.2` as well it has a routing rule enabling all multicast `224.0.0.0/4` -> `192.168.100.2`.
The remote server is running on Debian and has no GUI desktop installed.

All multicasts are generated by a streamer connected to the same Lan `192.168.100.x`.

When I am locally on site I plug my laptop which has GUI desktop to the local network (`192.168.100.x`) and use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) to play any video multicast channel to test and see if it is working properly.

For instance, `224.0.0.1` represent 1 video channel and using VLC by opening network stream `udp://@224.0.0.1:1234/` plays the video channel.

What I would like to accomplish is being able to probe the channels remotely, when not on site.

Is there any way I can use a SSH reverse tunnel to achieve that?

[image: Network scheme]

Answer (score 0):

One can pass received multicast UDP data over a TCP stream forwarded over SSH and do the reverse transformations on arrival. This requires `socat` in addition to SSH. If the Office PC is not running Linux, `socat` for non-Unix-like systems such as Windows can be found (eg: https://github.com/valorisa/socat-1.8.0.0_for_Windows).

Remarks about multicast:

- using 224.0.0.1 is the same as using a broadcast: even with a switch doing multicast snooping/querying, 224.0.0.1 is an exception (it's The *permanent* All Hosts multicast group) that doesn't require IGMP and will always be flooded everywhere, just as a broadcast: this defeats the role of *multicast* streaming. Choosing an address within 239.0.0.0/8 (and preferably first with something within 239.255.0.0/16) should be preferred: this range is intended for private use within an organization.
- "it has a routing rule enabling all multicast `224.0.0.0/4` -> `192.168.100.2`"

  If used (to alter the multicast destination for non-multicast aware senders), such route on Linux should be created with:

  ```
  ip route add multicast 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth1
  ```

  Even without they keyword `multicast`, Linux will force any address within 224.0.0.0/4 as being *multicast*. Anyway multicast-aware receivers such as `socat` can select the interface where multicast traffic is to be received, so this route command is not needed.

The order below is the order in which each tool should be run. It's almost but not exactly the reverse order of the flow.

1. Run the local `socat` command on the Office PC that will convert back 1234/TCP to (unicast) 1234/UDP (because neither `vlc` nor `mpv` accept directly a TCP stream in listen mode)

   ```
   socat TCP4-LISTEN:1234,bind=127.0.0.1,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:1234
   ```
2. Run the SSH command on the Office PC to create a reverse SSH tunnel for remote 1234/TCP

   ```
   ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 127.0.0.1:1234:127.0.0.1:1234 user@remoteserver
   ```

   This connection can be used later run the final remote `socat` command. Else it can also be kept in background with added options `-f -N`.
3. Prepare the `vlc` (or `mpv`) client in advance (the next bullets have to be done before VLC times out waiting for the stream).

   There's no multicast here. Simple unicast UDP receiver.

   ```
   vlc udp://:1234
   ```

   `mpv` would work as well:

   ```
   mpv udp://:1234
   ```
4. Run `socat` on the remote server to convert the multicast UDP stream into a TCP stream and send it through the tunnel

   ```
   socat -u UDP4-RECV:1234,ip-add-membership=224.0.0.1:eth1 TCP4:127.0.0.1:1234
   ```

   When the video client stops, this command will stop as well and will have to be restarted again *after* restarting the client.
5. Have the streaming server emit multicast on UDP 224.0.0.1:1234

   This can actually be done at any step.

When the video client in step 3. stops, the command in step 4. will also end and will have to be run again.

---

If the goal is to re-multicast in the office, then steps 1. and 3. on the Office PC can be replaced with:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:1234,bind=127.0.0.1,reuseaddr,fork UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.255.1.2:1234
```

to re-multicast the stream on 239.255.1.2:1234, which can then be received with:

```
vlc udp://239.255.1.2:1234
```

Step 4. won't have to be restarted each time for this case. If this is something preferred, while not intending to use multicast outside of the Office PC itself, then if it's running Linux, multicast could be restricted to the host with:

```
ip route add multicast 239.255.1.2 dev lo
```

or else to some dummy interface created for such use:

```
ip link add name dummymc up type dummy
ip route add multicast 239.255.1.2 dev dummymc
```

I have no idea on how to handle this on Windows.

---

Note: the stream data might be coalesced when going through TCP and SSH, which should not be an issue (it's a stream...). When coalescing happens, bigger UDP packets may be sent as fragmented IP packets if they hit the maximum size limit. This limit won't be reached on the loopback interface but would probably if re-multicasting. Normal systems don't have issues with IP fragments anyway. Using the TCP socket option TCP_NODELAY can help prevent this, but usually not completely. It can be used with OpenSSH by adding  `-o IPQoS='lowdelay lowdelay'` and with `socat` by adding `,nodelay` on TCP socket blocks.